# Data Attribute Access from Dynamically Added Select

Tags: javascript, select, dynamic, dropdown, custom-data-attribute

So far I have only seen examples getting data attribute from a select option that is already on the page, or added after a few seconds.

I'm looking at clicking a button, adding 3+ form fields which the one searchable dropdown field has a data tag in it with other information to use. Maybe I'm not going about it the right way.

**This is the generated options on the select**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $row['part_number']);
            $output .= "<option value=" .$row['id']. " data-sellprice=".$row['sell_price'].">" .$part. "</option>";
        }
```

**This is the Javscript that is creating the fields.**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     
     $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
      var html = '';
      html += '<tr>';
      
      html += '<td><select name="item_name[]" class="form-control fstdropdown-select item_name" id="swoparts"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($db); ?></select></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
      html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_price[]" class="form-control item_price" /></td>';
      html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
      $('#item_table').append(html);
      setFstDropdown();
     });
     
     $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });
 
 $("#swoparts").on("change", "select[name='item_name[]']", function(){
  console.log(this.value);
  })
});
</script>
```

I would like to get the data-sellprice from the option and display it in the item_price[] text field and use the amount to to keep adding to the other amounts of the form for a total.

I can make the data attribute work on a select that is already on the page when loaded.

*******EDITED PART******* NEED HELP HERE!!!!!!

I have gotten this far, please explain on what I have done and why its not working. I can make this all work for the select that created during the page creation or on document load. I CAN NOT make this work after the fact.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Item Name</th>
       <th>Enter Quantity</th>
       <th>Item Price</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="swoparts" class="swoparts">
                <option value="1" data-sellprice="55.00">Some thing we sell</option>
                <option value="2" data-sellprice="100.00">Something else we sell</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"><td>
        </tr>
     </table>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select.swoparts').change(function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("swoparts");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value 
        console.log(strUser);
    });
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
    $("#item_table").last().append('<td><select id="swoparts" class="swoparts"><option value="1" data-sellprice="55.00">Some thing we sell</option><option value="2" data-sellprice="100.00">Something else we sell</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td><td><input type="text" name="item_price[]" class="form-control item_price" id="sell_price" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>');  
 });
```

WHY can't I grab the information from the dynamically generated select?

I want 3 boxes added to my table, with a dropdown that is filled from a database where I can grab the dataset attribute and show it somewhere else and add it together with other dataset attributes from other added table rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle:

- Add Select box having option where data-* attribute is there.
- Then on change of the these select box value find the selected option
- Fetch the above option's data-* attrbite and add it.

https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/k6jxmgs9/21/

The JS code below:

```
function addFields() {
  const form1 = document.querySelector('#testform')
  const selectField = document.createElement('select');
  let dataView = null;
  [1, 2, 3].forEach((aVal) => {
    let optionElem = document.createElement('option');

    optionElem.setAttribute("value", aVal);
    optionElem.setAttribute("data-sellprice", "sell-" + aVal);
    optionElem.text = aVal;
    selectField.appendChild(optionElem);

  })
  selectField.addEventListener('change', () => {


    form1.querySelectorAll('option').forEach((opt) => {

      if (opt.value === selectField.value) {

        dataView = opt.getAttribute("data-sellprice");
      }
    })
    document.querySelector('#selectdData').innerHTML = dataView;
  });

  form1.appendChild(selectField);
```

Comment: Anyway you can you show me how you take what you created and incorporate it into what I originally posted as my layout? Like how come I just can't grab the data-* from the already created select?

Comment: From the already created select, have a onChange event like I have   selectField.addEventListener('change', () => { , then travserse through all the options and match which value is matching with Select element's value. Then fetch the data-* attribute of that option.